# 15minutes wait in between 2 JPATransactionManager class and DataSourceUtils

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, database-connection

If you see the below stacktrace then you can see that there is 15 minutes of waiting period to get a JDBC connection, I don't know why this happens?

```
2019-08-19 17:00:00.001 [97 ] [D] [] [gframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] | Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRep
ository.findOne]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
2019-08-19 17:00:00.002 [97 ] [D] [] [gframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] | Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@50b2c708] for JPA transac
tion
2019-08-19 17:15:25.663 [97 ] [D] [] [ramework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] | Setting JDBC Connection [ProxyConnection[PooledConnection[oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@1fee9
4dc]]] read-only
2019-08-19 17:15:25.663 [97 ] [D] [] [ine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] | begin
2019-08-19 17:15:25.664 [97 ] [D] [] [gframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] | Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@14724e8b]
```